# Tridion 2011 SQL connection problems

Tags: 2011-sp1

We are in the process of moving Tridion development in-house. To ensure environments are the same, we have restored a VMWare image of the dev CME server on our own network, and restored databases on our own SQL boxes.

We have applied new licences to match new CME box name, and have changed all the SQL configuration options to reference our own SQL instance.

When browsed the CME site authenticates a user successfully but when loading the left hand content menu it throws a named pipes connection error. Using Fiddler this is associated with a call to the TCM54 service.

We have verified that named pipes is enabled and that the CME IIS can communicate with SQL Server (using MS PortQryv2 and WireShark)...and we're assuming that if it couldn't communicate it wouldn't authenticate the user.

However, Wireshark does show that something is still trying to connect to the SQL Server on the other environment. We have searched config files for references to previous SQL server but drawn a blank.

So the question is where else could a database connection string be configured, and has anyone else had similar issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database connections are configured for the CM Kernel (using TCM Config MMC snap-in), but also for some optional modules: Translation Manager and Audience Manager.  Maybe you're using TM and/or AM and haven't changed their DB config yet?

A callstack (obtained from the Windows Event Log) should reveal in which context the connection error occurs.

Comment: Ok, I'll check. We have configured changes using snap-in. We are definitely not using TM but would AM affecting CME loading?

Comment: Yes, AM integrates in the CME.

Comment: Thanks Rick spot on (although we don't use AM it is installed). Database config section encrypted in OutboundEmail.xml. I didn't have access to media and unencrypt cmd so copied in plain text section. Still got named pipes error, so something else to be sorted, however, IP address of Sql works fine.